# heroku deploy docker image with github

Tags: node.js, docker, github, heroku

I have a nodejs express app serving a site. I deployed it with Heroku, using buildpack/nodejs and Github. Every time i push on Github, Heroku detects the push and runs the npm start script.

The problem is that I need to pass to a Docker image containing the nodejs app. I did it and it works locally, I can run it with `docker run -d -p 8000:8000 exporter` and it works.

I added the docker.yml file on the root folder and pushed on Github. But heroku still runs the npm script in the package.json, ignoring the docker.yml.

Is there a way to make heroku create the container from the Dockerfile every time I push to Github?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

Comment: Thank you, I did it that way and it works. The problem is that I had to do it by the heroku cli. It is not connected with github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of Taylor Cochran I managed to solve the problem.

I first tried to follow this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime

It worked but I had to do it from the cli.

After that I removed the entire project and remade it. I followed the indications of Taylor Cochran and pushed from heroku cli. I saw it worked and I then added the github deploy. And now every time I push on Github the new Docker container is automatically built and deployed by Heroku.

NB: I changed `web: docker run -d -p 8000:8000 exporter` to `npm start`

Comment: did you use a database in your project? I couldn't find a way to pass database url that was present in the heroku config vars to my docker.

Comment: No, I actually needed only mongoexport tool in my project because it only exported data from other databases and formatted it. This is the project https://github.com/euberdeveloper/eagletrt-telemetria-exporter

Comment: I see, Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Naresh you can use the `release` phase of heroku

Answer (score 2):

For Heroku to understand your `heroku.yml` file you need a few things.
First off you need to make sure that the `Dockerfile` is in the root directory.
Second, you need to ensure you are building and running the docker environment.
Finally, make sure you set your heroku stack to `docker`.

So, given that we want to ensure the directory tree looks like this:

```
|-my_app
     |-app_contents
|-Dockerfile
|-heroku.yml
|-etc...
```

And that the `heroku.yml` file looks something like this:

```
build:
   docker:
      web: Dockerfile
run:
   web: docker run -d -p 8000:8000 exporte
```

and finally run this in your heroku repo:

```
heroku stack:set container
```

Then just make sure you push your changes up.

If this doesn't help. I would recommend updating your post with the following:

1. The file tree
2. The Dockerfile
3. The heroku.yml file